# How to improve the rig in blender to prevent weird mesh deformations?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender, 3d-modelling, makehuman

I generated a character in makehuman and imported it blender. I have neither used Mhx rig or rigify as they will decrease performance due to lots of bones. I just used simple HumanIK rig. But, the rig doesn't contain any IK bones, so I created them myself. But, now I am having a problem that the deformations of mesh are not that natural. On rotating upper shoulder character rotates in weird way and on rotating hip the character hip mesh gets deformed. It is hard to explain the exact things happening. Just the problem I said. So, is there Any blender user who has good experience with rigging? I just need few suggestions to improve my character rig :/ ? You can get the .blend file from here: https://www.datafilehost.com/d/01d07ddd

When rotating upper spine:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZteaU.jpg)

Comment: Please remove the tag "game-engine", because your usage is against the tag description.

Comment: actually the model is for a game engine, as I mentioned the performance thing. Should I metion about the game engine in question too?

Comment: For example, I have a question about my Algorithm-library for a game.  Suppose that my question can stand by itself (solid & complete) - without need to describe anything about  the game.   In that case, I will not use "game"/"game-engine" tag.   ..... it is up to you, though.

Comment: actually I used that because I was hoping an answer from game developers, so, that I get the game specific suggestion as this rig is for game.